# Unable to make Custom shape for a Image (Remote Image) in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am having trouble making a custom shape with Border in Android as per the attached image. [image]

I have tried using [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) library to make the shape, but it gives me round corner only.. How can i achieve exactly as the attached image? I tried using a png file overlap in top of image but it doesn't give the desired out put. Also the mage can very in size (Some places small, some places bigger etc.)

Current code which gives roundrect corner as below.

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siRadius="6dp"
    app:siBorderWidth="6dp"
    app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"
    app:siSquare="true"/>
```

**Edit**

I am not sure why people giving downvote.. If you have dare , then comment here what makes you to give downvote. And read the question carefully.. I am not asking for round corner image view.. thats very simple, i need a custom shape as per the image & that is not just the round corner.

Comment: I am not sure why people giving downvote.. If you have dare , then comment here what makes you to give downvote. And read the question carefully.. I am not asking for round corner image view.. thats very simple, i need a custom shape as per the image & that is not just the round corner.

Answer (score 0):

try this library [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: This should be a comment !

Comment: Yeah.. the library didnt give a proper solution. Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `app:siRadius="6dp"` to some number that meets your requirement, like `app:siRadius="10dp"`

Comment: Yeah tried, but never got proper shape for different sized images.

Comment: how is it looking can u share 2 diff images in a link?

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
 public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth = 400;
    int targetHeight = 400;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = null;
    if (scaleBitmapImage != null) {
        targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
                new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                        sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    }
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me check and get back.

Comment: actually it just gives round corner, what i need is entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a resource that represents your ImageView`s border. Fell free to change it according your necessities:

**res/drawable/image_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" 
        android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/default_back_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now, set a style to use it in your `ImageView`:

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="imageViewStyle">
    <!-- 3dp so the background border to be visible -->
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image_border</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>
```

And then, use it in your `ImageView` :

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/my_image" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"               
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/imageViewStyle"
    android:src="@drawable/some_image"/>
```

Comment: Thank you.. Let me check with the solution.